# Angular 11 and ng2-charts

Tags: json, angular, ng2-charts

I decide to install ng2-charts for my Angular project: https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/

The main problem is when I update angular.json file, the compiler gave me several errors, as it follows:

**barras.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-barras',
  templateUrl: './barras.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class BarrasComponent implements OnInit {

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{}] },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public randomize(): void {
    // Only Change 3 values
    this.barChartData[0].data = [
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      59,
      80,
      (Math.random() * 100),
      56,
      (Math.random() * 100),
      40 ];
  }
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.9",
    "chart.js": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "graficasApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["chart.js"],
            "outputPath": "dist/graficasApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "graficasApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "graficasApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "graficasApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "graficasApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "graficasApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "graficasApp"
}
```

**Angular CLI Windows console**

[image: CMD Windows compiler error]

[image: Browser compiler]

What is the best way to solve this kind of graph package?

Comment: Are you importing the Chart package?

Comment: @Ion Yes, import { ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

Comment: Are you using charts 3? Have you tried this `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';`?

Comment: @Ion These versions from the edit, 3.2.1 and 2.4.2, from the two packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the `Chart.js` types package. `npm i @types/chart.js`.

The types definition package is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chart.js.